# Get firexfox developer toolbar on a different tab or popout

Tags: html, css, configuration, firefox-addon

I hope the question police have something better to do while I can get some much needed information.

I try to do my HTML and CSS on firefox using the Web Developer Toolbar addon. It saves a lot of time but I have a very simple question. I have searched all the options in the addon. Is there a way to get this thing to pop-out like firebug. Cause it takes up half the screen while doing the page and that becomes a pain really fast.

I know its a very simple question but if you can help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with it and it seems you are right.  It doesn't have a "separate window/tab" feature.  But here are two thoughts for what they're worth.

1. I assume you have dual monitors cuz of your question.  There's a [position] icon next to the "Edit HTML" and "Edit CSS" tabs.  (it looks like a lil window with a green arrow.  Click on it to reposition the editor to the left or right of your browser, then minimize FF and stretch it across your monitors :D haha!  but seriously, I tried it and it works perfectly!!
2. Lame answer: If that doesn't suit you, ask Chris Pederick on the WDT forum: http://chrispederick.com/forums/

Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks for the second link. http://chrispederick.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=2369 -- that feature is in the pipeline.  unfortunately I don't have a second monitor(yet). Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: You're welcome DMin! Good find. By the way, second monitor is the way to go.  It will pay itself off in a week.